# Spring MVC File Upload - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm getting (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect) error, when I try to access the following method.

```
@RequestMapping ( value = "/prospect/prospectupdated", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String prospectUpdated ( @ModelAttribute("prospect") CustomProspectList customProspectList, @RequestParam("consentForm") MultipartFile file ) throws IOException {

        int id = customProspectList.getProsId();

        String consentFormStatus = prospectService.consentFormStatus(id);

        byte[] consentFormFile = file.getBytes();
        String consentFormName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        long consentFormSize = file.getSize();
        String consentFormType = file.getContentType();

        if ( consentFormStatus.equals("Y") && consentFormSize != 0 ){
            prospectService.updateConsentForm(id, consentFormName, consentFormSize, consentFormFile, consentFormType);
        }

        return "success";
    }
```

**JSP part for file upload :**

```
<form:input path="prosConsentForm" id="consentForm" type="file" style="display:initial" name="consentForm"/>
```

**DAO implementation method :**

```
@Override
    public void updateConsentForm(int id, String consentFormName, long consentFormSize, byte[] consentFormFile, String consentFormType) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "UPDATE ccm_prospect SET PROS_Consent_Form_Name = :ConsentFormName, PROS_Consent_Form_Size = :ConsentFormSize, PROS_Consent_Form_File = :ConsentFormFile, PROS_Consent_Form_Type = :ConsentFormType WHERE PROS_Id = :ProspectId";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("ConsentFormName", consentFormName);
        query.setParameter("ConsentFormSize", consentFormSize);
        query.setParameter("ConsentFormFile", consentFormFile);
        query.setParameter("ConsentFormType", consentFormType);
        query.setParameter("ProspectId", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

**Help me here :**

This is the customProspectList model class.

```
public class CustomProspectList {

    private int prosId;

    private String prosDOB;

    private String prosTrackingStatus;

    private String prosFirstName;

    private String prosLastName;

    private String prosMiddleName;

    private String prosGender;

    private String prosEmail;

    private String prosMobilePhone;

    private String prosHomePhone;

    private String prosWorkPhone;

    private String prosCommuMethod;

    private String prosAddrLine1;

    private String prosAddrLine2;

    private String prosCity;

    private String prosState;

    private String prosZipCode;

    private byte[] prosConsentForm;

    private byte[] prosHippaForm;

    private String prosConsentFormName;

    private String prosHippaFormName;

    private String prosConsentFormDate;

    private String prosHippaFormDate;

    private BigInteger prosConsentFormSize;

    private BigInteger prosHippaFormSize;

    private String provNPI;

    private String faciName;

    private String faciAddrState;

    private String persFirstName;

    private String persLastName;

    private String persMiddleName;

    private String prosConsentFormType;

    //getters & setters
```

**This is the form :**

```
<form:form commandName="prospect" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/prospect/prospectupdated" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
  ........
  </form:form>
```

Comment: Please, add full stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not getting any stack trace in console, i'm getting HTTP Status 400 -  only...with this description "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.".

Comment: Please post the complete http form as well as the `CustomProspectList` class, it is likely that the problem is relation to them. Btw: your form must have the multipart parameter set and you need a registeres MultipartResolver / Filter in Spring. https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: yeah, i have registered the MultipartResolver in spring config file.

Comment: any one knows the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your file to :

```
private MultipartFile prosConsentForm;
```

instead of a byte array.

If this doesn't work just turn your logger to debug for org.springframework

For every 40X error spring doesn't write error log but in debug it will cleary tell you the reason.